# Costa Rican Centipede Species

Tags: species-identification, arthropod

What species of centipede is this?
Found it 3 miles from San Ramón, Costa Rica

[image: Centipede? Type?]

Comment: I appreciate the coin for the scale but honestly, I have no idea what the diameter of a 500 colones coin is :D